# Columns in Kivy RecycleView not displaying all items

Tags: python, kivy

I am finding it difficult to display 7 columns of items using Kivy RecycleView. I observed that if set the column length/length of the items list (self.columns) less to actual length of my items list e.g. 6, the 7 columns appear but not on a single row as expected. I will like to get all the items in the list display on a single row of 7 columns. Thank you in advance.

I am using python 3.7 on a virtual environment created in Anaconda.

Here is my code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
# from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout


items = ['First Name', 'Last Name', 'Email', 'Phone Number', 'Fax','Address 1', 'Address 2'] 

Builder.load_string('''
<DataTable>:
    id: main_win
    RecycleView:
        viewclass: 'CustLabel'
        id: table_floor
        RecycleGridLayout:
            id: table_floor_layout
            cols: 7
            default_size: (None,250)
            default_size_hint: (1,None)
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.minimum_height
            spacing: 5
<CustLabel@Label>:
    bcolor: (1,1,1,1)
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: root.bcolor
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
''')
class DataTable(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.columns = len(items)
        
        table_data = []
        for t in items:
            table_data.append({'text':str(t),'size_hint_y':None,'height':50,'bcolor':(.06,.45,.45,1)})
            # table_data.append({'text':str(t)})

        self.ids.table_floor_layout.cols = self.columns
        self.ids.table_floor.data = table_data
    
class DataTableApp(App):
    def build(self):

        return DataTable()

if __name__=='__main__':
    DataTableApp().run()
```

Comment: That is how a `RecycleGridLayout` works. If you set `cols` to less than the actual number of columns, they will get wrapped around. The columns are filled left to right, then top to bottom. If you want 7 items in each row, then set `cols` to 7.

Comment: Thank you @JohnAnderson. I am very new to Kivy.  Could you please help me run my code. I preset the cols to 5 in the KV part. In implementing it, I control the number of cols using the the length of the actual data. In my case, only the first item displayed. Thanks once again.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i had the same problem. I finally solved it by adding a database. It means when your database is empty you won't be able to display all the columns. This will create a database with the desired columns. So here is how you can create a Mongo database:
create a .py file called **testdb** and add to it this source code:

```
import pymongo

client = pymongo.MongoClient('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017')
mydb = client['silverpos']

products = mydb.stocks

record = {
    'product_code': '14527',
    'product_name': 'Jely',
    'product_weight': '45',
    'in_stock': '400',
    'sold': '678',
    'order': 'wesd',
    'last_purchase': '23 june'
}

products.insert_one(record)
```

After that, you will have a running database as a service. Try to display your GUI again with 7 as several columns or [you know, do the math]